# What's the opposite of "Header append Vary User-Agent", how to remove the "User-Agent" string from "Vary"?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I know that I can add the `User-Agent` to the `Vary` http header with this line in my .htacess:

```
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

But how can I remove the `User-Agent` from the `Vary` header if it is already set?

According to the [mod_headers doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) there is an `append` option, but no equivalent "remove" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer below, but you need some shenanigans to avoid sending an empty Vary: header (try to avoid it out of paranoia)

```
Header edit Vary (.*)User-Agent(.*) $1$2
# Remove leading or trailing ',' without making things complex above
Header edit Vary ^,?(.*),?$ $1
# 2.4-only: remove empty Vary header
Header unset Vary "expr=resp('Vary') =~ /^$/"
```

x-never-match can be any unlikely-to-ever-be-used header name.

Comment: Thx! Good idea using `edit`, but what if there is a `,` before `User-Agent` like in `Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent`?

Comment: I also think, I can neigther accept an empty `Vary` nor a dummy `Vary` header, because my hoster runs a varnish cache in front of the apache. Varnish will not work with this. Would a `if (is Vary empty) then Header unset Vary` be possible? I do not know how to test for an empty `Vary` header

Comment: I think having a trailing or leading slash is safe, I wasn't super excited about trying to make the single regex avoid those in the capture and making it a real eye-buster. 

In 2.4, mod_headers can use an expr= condition and you could check if it was exactly ^User-Agent$ and unset it.  If you're on 2.4, I can probably test the syntax and add it to the answer.

Comment: edited for 2.4 and to remove leading/trailingcommas (but in a separate invocation)

Answer (score 4):

Though this is not as generic as being able to remove the specific `User-Agent` keyword, it gets the job done:

```
Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
```

This will overwrite your existing header so that the `vary` header will only have `Accept-Encoding`