# How to disable vary User-Agent from response header in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I have tried a few .htaccess commands like RequestHeader unset User-Agent

but it isn't working. I also removed compression to check whether it was trigerring User-Agent or not but it wasn't.

Could you tell me how to remove Vary User-Agent from my response header. I think it is there by default.

Might it be that it has to be done from cPanel & WHM. If that is the case then could you guide me on how to do it?

Or if it is to be done through .htaccess then also I need your help on how to do it.

Here's how my .htaccess currently looks like:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# |     Web fonts access                                                           |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow access from all domains for web fonts

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
```

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Compression                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-eot
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/svg
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype


# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
 BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Add Expiry and Unset Pragma and ETag                                       |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Header unset Pragma

# 1 Month for most static assets 3 months for proxies
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, s-maxage=7776000, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>


# 3 Days for normal and 1 week for proxies
<filesMatch ".(css|xml|html|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, s-maxage=604800, must-revalidate,   proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And I have also tried **Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the opposite of "Header append Vary User-Agent", how to remove the "User-Agent" string from "Vary"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228682/whats-the-opposite-of-header-append-vary-user-agent-how-to-remove-the-user)